# How to plot rectangles on a video frame based upon information in a csv file

Tags: matlab, csv

I have managed to read in a video file frame by frame

```
infile= ['baseballField.avi'];
readerobj=VideoReader(infile);
groundtruth = csvread('baseballField-groundtruth.top');
for i=1:2:20
    vidframe=read(readerobj,i); 
    imshow(vidframe);               
    drawnow                     
end
```

I have also read in the csv file as can be seen above. Each record of the csv file contains values that tag each person in the video, the number of the frame and the box coordinates of the body of the person.

I would like to plot the body bounding boxes for each person in each video frame, overlaid atop the video data. How would i plot this data?

Comment: What format are your rectangles specified in?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in [`rectangle`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rectangle.html?refresh=true) function to plot a rectangle on your current axes.

```
imshow(vidframe);
hold on
rectangle('Position', [x,y,width,height])
```

As a sidenote, you're creating a new image everytime through your loop. It's better to store the handle to the image object and just update the `CData` property of the image within the loop.

```
infile= ['baseballField.avi'];
readerobj=VideoReader(infile);
groundtruth = csvread('baseballField-groundtruth.top');

vidframe = read(readerobj, 1);
him = imshow(vidframe);
hold on
hrect = rectangle('Position', pos{1});
drawnow

for k = 1:2:20  
    set(him, 'CData', read(readerobj, k));
    set(hrect, 'Position', pos{k}) 
    drawnow                     
end
```

Comment: Apologies... i meant to plot a bounding box for a player on the baseball field, not a rectangle.